Can't see file changes/updates/creation in volumes in Docker
I am not sure what I am doing wrong with this. I am in the process of converting our python apps into Docker containers. During this development process I want to confirm everything is working correctly by reviewing the output logs, files, etc on my Windows machine however I cannot get volumes working so I can create or move files on the container and then have them be visible on the host Windows machine for A. persistance and B. review.
For example,
My DockerFile
# Purpose: Set the base image.
FROM debian:12
 
# Purpose: Set the working directory.
WORKDIR /app
 
# Purpose: Copy the contents of the app directory to the working directory.
COPY app/ .
 
# Purpose: Set the environment variables for Python.
ENV PYTHON_VERSION 3.12.3
ENV PATH /usr/local/bin:$PATH
ENV LANG C.UTF-8
ENV GPG_KEY 7169605F62C751356D054A26A821E680E5FA6305
 
# Purpose: Set the environment variables for pip.
 
# Purpose: Commands for installing packages & app dependencies.
RUN apt-get update && apt-get -y upgrade
RUN apt-get install -y --no-install-recommends \
        autoconf \
        automake \
        bzip2 \
        ca-certificates \
        default-libmysqlclient-dev \
        dpkg-dev \
        file \
        g++ \
        gcc \
        gnupg2 \
        imagemagick \
        libbz2-dev \
        libc6-dev \
        libcurl4-openssl-dev \
        libdb-dev \
        libevent-dev \
        libffi-dev \
        libgdbm-dev \
        libglib2.0-dev \
        libgmp-dev \
        libjpeg-dev \
        libkrb5-dev \
        liblzma-dev \
        libmagickcore-dev \
        libmagickwand-dev \
        libmaxminddb-dev \
        libncurses5-dev \
        libncursesw5-dev \
        libpng-dev \
        libpq-dev \
        libreadline-dev \
        libsqlite3-dev \
        libssl-dev \
        libtool \
        libwebp-dev \
        libxml2-dev \
        libxslt-dev \
        libyaml-dev \
        make \
        patch \
        unzip \
        xz-utils \
        zlib1g-dev \
        libbluetooth-dev \
        uuid-dev \
        tk-dev \ 
        wget 
 
RUN set -eux; \
    \
    wget -O python.tar.xz "https://www.python.org/ftp/python/${PYTHON_VERSION%%[a-z]*}/Python-$PYTHON_VERSION.tar.xz"; \
    wget -O python.tar.xz.asc "https://www.python.org/ftp/python/${PYTHON_VERSION%%[a-z]*}/Python-$PYTHON_VERSION.tar.xz.asc"; \
    GNUPGHOME="$(mktemp -d)"; export GNUPGHOME; \
    gpg --batch --keyserver hkps://keys.openpgp.org --recv-keys "$GPG_KEY"; \
    gpg --batch --verify python.tar.xz.asc python.tar.xz; \
    gpgconf --kill all; \
    rm -rf "$GNUPGHOME" python.tar.xz.asc; \
    mkdir -p /usr/src/python; \
    tar --extract --directory /usr/src/python --strip-components=1 --file python.tar.xz; \
    rm python.tar.xz; \
    \
    cd /usr/src/python; \
    gnuArch="$(dpkg-architecture --query DEB_BUILD_GNU_TYPE)"; \
    ./configure \
        --build="$gnuArch" \
        --enable-loadable-sqlite-extensions \
        --enable-optimizations \
        --enable-option-checking=fatal \
        --enable-shared \
        --with-lto \
        --with-system-expat \
        --without-ensurepip \
    ; \
    nproc="$(nproc)"; \
    EXTRA_CFLAGS="$(dpkg-buildflags --get CFLAGS)"; \
    LDFLAGS="$(dpkg-buildflags --get LDFLAGS)"; \
    make -j "$nproc" \
        "EXTRA_CFLAGS=${EXTRA_CFLAGS:-}" \
        "LDFLAGS=${LDFLAGS:-}" \
        "PROFILE_TASK=${PROFILE_TASK:-}" \
    ; \
# https://github.com/docker-library/python/issues/784
# prevent accidental usage of a system installed libpython of the same version
    rm python; \
    make -j "$nproc" \
        "EXTRA_CFLAGS=${EXTRA_CFLAGS:-}" \
        "LDFLAGS=${LDFLAGS:--Wl},-rpath='\$\$ORIGIN/../lib'" \
        "PROFILE_TASK=${PROFILE_TASK:-}" \
        python \
    ; \
    make install; \
    \
# enable GDB to load debugging data: https://github.com/docker-library/python/pull/701
    bin="$(readlink -ve /usr/local/bin/python3)"; \
    dir="$(dirname "$bin")"; \
    mkdir -p "/usr/share/gdb/auto-load/$dir"; \
    cp -vL Tools/gdb/libpython.py "/usr/share/gdb/auto-load/$bin-gdb.py"; \
    \
    cd /; \
    rm -rf /usr/src/python; \
    \
    find /usr/local -depth \
        \( \
            \( -type d -a \( -name test -o -name tests -o -name idle_test \) \) \
            -o \( -type f -a \( -name '*.pyc' -o -name '*.pyo' -o -name 'libpython*.a' \) \) \
        \) -exec rm -rf '{}' + \
    ; \
    \
    ldconfig; \
    \
    python3 --version
 
# make some useful symlinks that are expected to exist ("/usr/local/bin/python" and friends)
RUN set -eux; \
    for src in idle3 pydoc3 python3 python3-config; do \
        dst="$(echo "$src" | tr -d 3)"; \
        [ -s "/usr/local/bin/$src" ]; \
        [ ! -e "/usr/local/bin/$dst" ]; \
        ln -svT "$src" "/usr/local/bin/$dst"; \
    done
 
# if this is called "PIP_VERSION", pip explodes with "ValueError: invalid truth value '<VERSION>'"
ENV PYTHON_PIP_VERSION 24.0
# https://github.com/pypa/get-pip
ENV PYTHON_GET_PIP_URL https://github.com/pypa/get-pip/raw/dbf0c85f76fb6e1ab42aa672ffca6f0a675d9ee4/public/get-pip.py
ENV PYTHON_GET_PIP_SHA256 dfe9fd5c28dc98b5ac17979a953ea550cec37ae1b47a5116007395bfacff2ab9
 
RUN set -eux; \
    \
    wget -O get-pip.py "$PYTHON_GET_PIP_URL"; \
    echo "$PYTHON_GET_PIP_SHA256 *get-pip.py" | sha256sum -c -; \
    \
    export PYTHONDONTWRITEBYTECODE=1; \
    \
    python get-pip.py \
        --disable-pip-version-check \
        --no-cache-dir \
        --no-compile \
        "pip==$PYTHON_PIP_VERSION" \
    ; \
    rm -f get-pip.py; \
    \
    pip --version
 
RUN pip install -r requirements.txt
 
# Specify the command to run when the container starts
# For example, let's just run a bash shell
CMD ["bash"]

My build script
docker build . --tag "0005" --no-cache

My start script
docker run --rm -it -v /x/project/0005/data:/app/data 0005

I can see the files in /app/data when the container gets launched. So the paths are correct, but if I run touch 1234.txt in the docker container, I cannot see it on the windows PC. Vice versa if after I launch the container and then I make a file in X:\Project\0005\data\1234.txt in Windows, it does not show up in the container until I restart it.

Please [edit] the question to include any relevant source code directly in the question, not behind a link.  What path is the container trying to use to write the file?  /app/data from the mount and ./app/data relative to the current directory will usually be different places.

@DavidMaze apologies, I meant /app/data in the container. I am editing the post to clarify.
